# Repeat output x amount of times to the right and down

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

I am almost on track here. I need to output if the user enters 5 or any number, the program should display the following:

xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx

5 to the right going down 5 times.

I have the right idea so far. But i am not sure how to specifiy it to repeat the the xxxxx going down 5 times as well. I tried making a forloop but it didnt work as well as this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int inputInteger = 0;
char letterX = 'x';
cout << "input a integer" << endl;
cin >> inputInteger;

    for (int i=0; i<=inputInteger; i++)
    {
        cout << letterX;

        if ( i == inputInteger)
        {
            cout << endl;
            i = 0;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two loops:

```
for (int i=0; i!=inputInteger; ++i) {
  for (int j=0; j!=inputInteger; ++j) {
    cout << letterX;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that maybe its because i put an = instead if != that means not equal to right?

Comment: that's right -- you want to keep looping as long as i is not equal to your inputInteger.  Think of it like  "while i is not equal to inputInteger".  A for loop is similar to a while loop.

Comment: Okay i see, i just didnt understand that concept. It just gets a bit confusing but i think i am starting to udnerstand it! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop within a loop, the outer one looping over the lines to be printed and the inner one looping over the characters. Don't get fancy here; there's no need for getting fancy here.

Comment: Yeah i did what he showed up above but i made it = to instead of != why is it that = did not work?